# What's the difference between a "database engine" and a "query engine"?

Tags: database

From the context I keep reading these two terms in, it seems that they are about equivalent. However, does anyone know if there are any significant differences between the two in how they are used, and how they are designed?

Additional background on how these fit into the concepts of "DBMS" and "databases" for a noob/newbie would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind :

A query can ask for data, actions or else and can have many forms (SQL, JSON, custom language...). So a query is the message of an user/backend request in a software.

A database stocks your data and process requests for rendering it. Every existing database nowadays has an engine to process those request, so they have a query engine that is a part of the whole database engine called DBMS; but here, it will only respond to the right data query (SQL or JSON, depends on database).

But a query engine can be totally implemented to respond to other types of queries; for example you want to render a result to a calculation query that you have designed... You need an engine to process the query that has been sent, to calculate the result and to send it back to whatever instance asked for it.